# How to render TreeNode after changing node.attributes?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am updating the attributes of Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode. After updating, i want to render the updated values on UI. This node is already rendered, how can I rerender the same treeNode with new updated attributes value?

I am using uiProvider for TreeNode i.e. attr.uiProvider = Ext.ux.tree.TreeGridNodeUI

Comment: On ExtJS 6, tree node has a triggerUIUpdate method. There's also a reload() method. See http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/docs/#!/api/Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode

Comment: Thanks @DiegoVictordeJesus. But I am looking for extjs3.4 version. By the way I got similar solution here  https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?36430-How-to-render-TreeNode-after-changing-node-attributes.

Comment: Please post your solution here and accept it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function refreshNodeColumns(n)
{
    var t = n.getOwnerTree();
    var a = n.attributes;
    var cols = t.columns;
    var el = n.ui.getEl().firstChild; // <div class="x-tree-el">
    var cells = el.childNodes;
    
    //<div class="x-tree-col"><div class="x-tree-col-text">
    
    for(var i = 1, len = cols.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        var d = cols[i].dataIndex;
        var v = (a[d]!=null)? a[d] : '';
        if (cols[i].renderer) v = cols[i].renderer(v);
        cells[i].firstChild.innerHTML = v;        
    }
}
```